# Permission denied in Civi\Core\AssetBuilder->build()

Tags: drupal, permissions

I just upgraded CiviCRM on a test version of my Drupal 7.54 site from 4.7.15 to 4.7.23 and get the following (edited) error when going to system status in CiviCRM.

> Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in Civi\Core\AssetBuilder->build()
>   (line 167 of
>   sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/Civi/Core/AssetBuilder.php).
>   Warning:
>   file_put_contents(sites/default/files/civicrm/persist/contribute/dyn/angular-modules.eef75e30334ca152b0d58bf58d4xxxxx.js):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   Civi\Core\AssetBuilder->build() (line 171 of
>   sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/Civi/Core/AssetBuilder.php)

I made sure that I deleted templates_c and made it and all CiviCRM files writeable to the server.

Comment: I've had the same issue with an upgrade of CiviCRM database in Wordpress.  I think the database must have some references to old resource files as I have also deleted caches.

Answer (score 2):

This suggests a file permission issue on the relevant folder - which is `sites/default/files/civicrm/persist/contribute/dyn/`.

First, ensure the parent folders exist - both `sites/default/files/civicrm/persist/contribute/dyn/` and `sites/default/files/civicrm/persist/contribute/`.  If both exist, check the permission AND owner of the `dyn` folder.  Is the owner the same user as the webserver user?  Likewise, if `dyn` doesn't exist do the same for `contribute`.  If you're not sure how to check owner/permissions, or how to interpret them, please either a) hop on https://chat.civicrm.org, or b) update the question with your operating system (including the distribution, if Linux) and webserver software (most likely Apache or nginx).

Comment: What's interesting is that the dyn directory didn't exist. Since it was on a test site, I undid the upgrade for now but will revisit the issue when I upgrade officially and see if it's still an issue. It was probably a caching issue since it was asking for a file that doesn't exist.

Comment: CiviCRM will create the `dyn` directory, but it may not have had the permissions to do so.  Which is odd - there's a permission check that runs daily that will flag if there's an issue.  Since it's a test site, I suspect that either a) the check didn't have a chance to run, or b) your Directories settings are different.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in WordPress.
I believe the issue is caused because the upgrade script requires resource files to be in their expected place from the old version.  So, if you've created a new install and are just migrating a database, then the error may be triggered.

The resource locations have changed between database versions, so the update script fails if it can't find the old resource files.

I fixed this by copying the old resource files to the expected location (as they are listed in the error - in my case this was `plugins/files/civicrm`).

For reference, I was updating the CiviCRM database from 4.7.9 to 5.13.5 on Wordpress 5.11.
Once the files are available, the update should run (In my case, I  needed to retrigger the update with http://example.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/upgrade&reset=1)